# Extraño problema con las rutas de las imagenes

Tags: laravel-5

Veran, tengo la tabla Foto, con estas variables:

```
    Schema::create('fotos', function(Blueprint $table){
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('foto')->unique();
        $table->string('nombre')->unique();
        $table->date('fecha');
        $table->unsignedInteger('categoria_id');
        $table->foreign('categoria_id')->references('id')->on('categorias');
    });
```

La variable `foto` es la que indica la imagen, que esta en `public/archivo`.
Accedo a ella mediante esta función:

```
public function ruta(){
    return "archivo/".$this->foto;
}
```

Esto me sirve si quiero usar la imagen en una vista.
El problema es que en algunas vistas esto no funciona.

Pruebo con una vista llamada `/crear_noticia`:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y esta todo bien.

Pruebo ahora `articulo_comentarios/{(id del articulo)}`:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pruebo entonces otra vista llamada `/categoria_filtrar/{(id de la categoria)}`, que es como la primera vista, pero filtrando las fotos por la variable `categoria_id`:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¡La imagen no esta!
¿A que se debe y como lo corrijo?

Comment: Prueba cambiar el return de tu funcion "ruta" a: return asset("archivo/".$this->foto), esto deberia devolverte la url a tu imagen y no una ruta relativa.

Comment: Pues esta funcionando.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba cambiar tu función `ruta` a:

```
public function ruta(){
    return asset("archivo/".$this->foto); 
}
```

Esto debería devolverte la URL a tu imagen y no una ruta relativa.

Aquí tienes mas información de la función [asset()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/helpers#method-asset)

Saludos!